# Stack jQuery ajaxComplete events

Tags: jquery, ajax

*Searched and didn't find what I was looking for*

Given that there's a whole heap of existing code, I want to append an ajaxComplete event

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log('always called');
  }
});
```

So that any existing code that may or may not implement ajaxComplete, will call it's existing complete function as well as the global complete function.

At the moment only 1 implementation exists so if I setup a global catch-all, anything setup later overrides the global one for that request and the code I need to execute at that point wont get executed.

```
$.ajax(...).always(function(){
  console.log('always called but prevents global');
});
```

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`ajaxComplete` will override the global callback, so you could do like below.

```
funciton foo() {
  console.log('always called');
}

$.ajaxSetup({
  complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    foo();
  }
});

$.ajax(...).ajaxComplete(function(){
  foo();
  console.log('always called but prevents global');
});
```

Comment: I don't want to prevent the global complete. I want the implementation of complete on the ajax call PLUS the global complete event to be triggered.

Comment: unfortunately this requires changes to existing code, which there's a LOT of, I'm trying to refactor all this code but without changing any existing code to begin with :(